# How to install Mac OS X Snow Leopard server on any virtual machine with DMG?

Tags: macos, installation, virtualbox, dmg-image, osx-server

I'm trying to install Mac OS X Snow Leopard Server on VirtualBox. I know this is duplicated question, however another questions have no fine answer.

I'm trying to install on VirtualBox on iMac. So this is pretty **legal**. But the problem is I want to install with DMG image. Because installing DVD drive is too slow, and I have to install Mac OS X many times. And taking DVD disc from box is annoying too.

But VirtualBox fails installing. It couldn't load kernel. It installs well with DVDs. Is there any way to do this?

I'm considering using other VM solutions like Parallels or VMWare if they can support install from DMG images well. If you know about them certainly, please let me know.

Comment: Eonil is correct. [Source.](http://db.tidbits.com/article/9277) It is legal to install OS X Server in a VM on a Mac, as long as one has the licenses for the additional VMs.

Comment: @Daniel where did it say Server in the post?

Comment: @slhck On the title, man. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the licenses, and if you need to create several VMs, why not build one VM from the DVD, and then make a copy of the Virtual Machine. As you need new instances, create a new copy, and add it into Virtual Box. I don't know if this is specifically supported by VBox, but I know it is by VMWare Fusion and Parallels. That way you save the time of constantly having to build the same server over and over again.

Comment: I couldn't event imagine copying VMs. Though it's one of the best feature of virtualization! Thanks!!! Anyway, do you know how it can be done via GUI? (on any solution)

Comment: Again, my experience with VBox is extremely limited. However with VMWare Fusion and Parallels, you simply build the machine, keeping note of where you indicated that the guest files should live. Once the machine is built, shut it down, and browse to the location with Finder. Make a copy of the VM, and name it something like MyVM-Template. From there, you ca make additional copies from the template as you need to; and add them in using the UI of the virtualization software. It should be pretty painless. The key is keeping your template in good shape.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of times the issue is improper hardware. Even though you are running OSX on your host, your CPU needs to support visualization to successfully run OSX Server within VirtualBox. I've had little luck doing so on any preCore-i host.

That being said, what are your system specs?

If you are using a newer processor that supports VTx then I would recommend reading this article:

> http://lifehacker.com/5583650/run-mac-os-x-in-virtualbox-on-windows

Comment: My Mac is i7 current model.